# I have an existing login I would like to make into a src react component

Tags: reactjs

I am making an app that requires a login (in code below). I attempted to refactor to a react component, so I can use in routing (login -> app body). No issues on vss but getting issues after npm start.

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object
>   '#'

```
import React from "react";

class DynamicLogin extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (module.exports = (app, passport) => {
      app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.render("index.ejs");
      });

      app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
        res.render("login.ejs", { message: req.flash("loginMessage") });
      });

      app.post(
        "/login",
        passport.authenticate("local-login", {
          successRedirect: "/profile",
          failureRedirect: "/login",
          failureFlash: true
        }),
        function(req, res) {
          if (req.body.remember) {
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
          } else {
            req.session.cookie.expires = false;
          }
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      );

      app.get("/signup", function(req, res) {
        res.render("signup.ejs", { message: req.flash("signupMessage") });
      });

      app.post(
        "/signup",
        passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
          successRedirect: "/profile",
          failureRedirect: "/signup",
          failureFlash: true
        })
      );

      app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render("profile.ejs", {
          user: req.user
        });
      });

      app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    });

    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();

      res.redirect("/");
    }
  }
}

export default DynamicLogin;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. From what I can see you're trying to convert your EJS views to react components. Unfortunately it is not as simple wrapping your existing EJS code in React syntax. React does not support the logic you use like module.exports and req/res.render like you typically see in EJS. Instead of EJS views, React employs JSX instead which is similar, but not the same as EJS. I'd recommend checking out Andrew Mead's React course to learn more about React's features: https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/

Otherwise, there is no direct connection between the code you are trying to integrate above with React.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess I currently have a naive understanding of react at the moment. I will check out the link you sent!